# How to store custom taxonomy name in a variable

Tags: php, wordpress, taxonomy

I'm looking to store a custom taxonomy name in a variable so I can use it in another section of my shortcode. I thought using the get_the_terms would work but i must be missing something.

```
$franchise = get_the_terms( $HeroID, 'hero-content' );
```

The post is registered to one item in the hero-content taxonomy and I need to be able to store the name of that in the variable $franchise or the slug.

edit: "hero-content" is the name of my custom taxonomy and I would like to store the name of the category I have selected under the "hero-content" taxonomy to be stored in the $franchise variable.

Comment: What is in $franchise then?

Comment: I would like $franchise to be the name of the category I have selected under the "hero-content" taxonomy.

Comment: `another section of my shortcode`: can we see the first and second sections?

Comment: It is pretty big and doesn't really have any relevance to this variable, I already have the post ID which is stored in $HeroID so I just need to figure out how to store the term's name inside a variable for my custom taxonomy.

Comment: @Greenhoe I mean when you try this, what does $franchise end up being?

Comment: It just says "array" when I output it

Answer (score 0):

This should be working fine, assuming the post with id of `$HeroID` is correct and your taxonomy is correct and that post is actually in that taxonomy.

You said its returning an array, well thats what happens when this function success, check "Returns" of [the codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_terms).

Do this to see if `$franchise` is anything;

```
<pre>
    <?php var_dump($franchise); ?>
</pre>
```

So the function has found that his post is actually has several terms of this taxonomy, and is return them all to you, in an array.

Any time you are using Wordpress functions (or any framework/PHPs functions) you should check the documentation to see what the params are (and what types) and also what the return values of the functions are.

Comment: When I do that it prints out "1" rather than the name of the term

Comment: Have updated the answer t use `var_dump` instead of `print_r`. Also, can you share the code from where you declare `$franchise` to where you try this `var_dump`.